# How to implement the Mac-style Windowshade feature for Windows

Tags: c#, vb.net

I always liked the WindowsShade utility on the Mac. Is there some sample code on how to do the same thing in VB.Net or C#.Net for Windows.

I have implemented it myself for a single app, but I would like to have it work for any window..

Answer (score 0):

To do it for any window would require hooking into the message processing for the entire system which is tricky business: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/netwin32hooks.aspx

But you don't need to write this yourself, unless you really want to. It's already been written, check it out: http://www.palma.com.au/winroll/

Comment: But is there any open source solution in C#? I happen to be looking for the same thing.